# What's the maximum span for a regular kitchen worktop?

Tags: kitchen-counters

I'm looking at using a regular laminated worktop as a desk in my office room. The room is just under 3m long - would I need to add a leg support in the middle if I attach it to the wall with a simple timber baton on three sides?

Something like this - http://www.wickes.co.uk/Worktop-Solid-Wood-Beech-28x600mmx3m/p/193142

Comment: We would need some more information; how heavy is your countertop? How are you planning on anchoring it to the wall (I don't quite understand timber baton, though)? Is this a dowel system you're using?

Answer (score 1):

On the plus side you have linked a solid timber top, and those are stiffer than most composite types. On the minus side, 3m is quite a long span for a 28mm thick slab of wood. Some sort of support in the middle would probably be advisable - a leg would work, you could also run some sort of beam under the top, or use large brackets to the wall (if you'd prefer to keep the floor under it clear.)

Comment: Thought as much.. easy option is an adjustable leg support in the middle somewhere I guess.